# How to clear sbt cache?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using `sbt 1.3.9` and I need to update some libraries that have changed its code but the version stays the same. When I tried to run `sbt update` command nothing happened the library not downloaded.
I have `sbt.build` file that looks like the following:

```
name := """project name"""
organization := "com.example"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
lazy val usr = sys.env("MVN_USER")

scalaVersion := "2.13.1"
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "11", "-target", "11")
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Jfrog Artifacts".at("https://artifactory.jfrog.com/")
)
credentials += Credentials(
  ...
)
updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withCachedResolution(false)
updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withLatestSnapshots(false)
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  guice,
  javaWs,
  ehcache,
  "com.google.api-client" % "google-api-client" % "1.30.7",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.9",
  "redis.clients" % "jedis" % "3.2.0"
)
```

how can I clear sbt cache?

Comment: ```sbt clean``` should do it

Comment: @sinanspd I tried this command but it is not working for me.

Comment: weird. I see you are using custom resolvers, any chance your package manager have some caching behavior?

Comment: On Linux, the sbt cache is in ~/.sbt, if you have some maven dependencies, those are stored in ~/.m2 . It should be safe to delete them, but perhaps just rename them for a beginning.

Answer (score 17):

You can just delete the `v1` folder.

The default [cache location](https://get-coursier.io/docs/cache.html#default-location) is platform-dependent:

> - on Linux, ~/.cache/coursier/v1. This also applies to Linux-based CI
>   environments, and FreeBSD too.
> - on OS X, ~/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1.
> - on Windows, %LOCALAPPDATA%\Coursier\Cache\v1, which, for user Alex,
>   typically corresponds to
>   C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Coursier\Cache\v1.

Answer (score 1):

I assuming that you are developing something locally and doing `publishLocal` - normal repository wouldn't let you override published dependency and snapshots are not cached (sbt checks if newer appeared every time you need to build sth).

In such case start using snapshot versions for the future and/or go to `~/.ivy2/your.organisation/library_scalaVersion` and remove whole directory with "bad" version. If library is fetched by Maven (with sbt, unlikely these days) it the same idea but with `~/.m2`.

Comment: I have been created a ```play 2``` application in the ```IntellijIdea IDE``` and I don't do any ```publishLocal```. I just start and stop my project using ```IntellijIdea tools``` like ```run``` and ```debug``` commands.

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced this while using IntelliJ. After closing IntelliJ, I used to clear .idea from project folder and reimport project into IntelliJ was helping me.

Answer (score -3):

You can use [PrettyClean](https://pretty-clean.github.io/) to clean the all of dev tools caches including SBT.

PrettyClean also cleans the SBT project's target folder.